# How to use loginRedirect instead of loginPopup?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement authentication for an Angular 2+ app using Azure AD B2C.  Found this great [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa). However the example does the authentication in a popup window.  I would prefer to use redirect instead of popup.  The code for the [MSAL Service](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa/blob/master/src/app/services/msal.service.ts) that does the popup authentication is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var bootbox: any;
declare var Msal:any;
@Injectable()
export class MsalService {

    access_token: string;

    tenantConfig = {
        tenant: "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
        clientID: '90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6',
        signUpSignInPolicy: "b2c_1_susi",
        b2cScopes: ["https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/demoapi/demo.read"]
    };

    // Configure the authority for Azure AD B2C

    authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;

    /*
     * B2C SignIn SignUp Policy Configuration
     */
    clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
        this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority, 
        function (errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
            // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
        }
    );

    public login(): void {
       var _this = this;
        this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken: any) {
            _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                function (accessToken: any) {
                    _this.access_token = accessToken;
                }, function (error: any) {
                    _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                        function (accessToken: any) {
                            _this.access_token = accessToken;
                        }, function (error: any) {
                            bootbox.alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                        });
                })
        }, function (error: any) {
            bootbox.alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
        });
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.clientApplication.logout();
    };

    isOnline(): boolean {
        return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null; 
    };
}
```

How do I change this code to do the same thing using `loginRedirect` instead of `loginPopup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take the code you have in `then` from `.loginPopup(blah).then()...` and put it in the block where `// Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup` is.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Would you happen to know why the `login` function in the above code calls both `acquireTokenSilent` as well as `acguireTokenPopup`?  It seems like it should call one or the other, but not both.

Comment: if it can't acquire a token silently then it will have to prompt the user to take some action like signing in again

Answer (score -1):

Instead of call the `loginPopup` for login, you can call `loginRedirect` function to interact with Azure AD for redirection instead of popup.

Comment: Yes, I figured that much.  But what about the rest of the code that follows `.loginPopup` (`.then(function ...`).  Where does that go?